# Com problemas no Assembly do C#. Não aceita o NPOI Atualizado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estou com uma dúvida. Estou tentando atualizar o NPOI de uma aplicação, porem ele estoura o seguinte erro:

> Falha ao exportar relatório (descrição: Não foi possível carregar
>   arquivo ou assembly 'NPOI, Version=1.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=0df73ec7942b34e1' ou uma de suas dependências. A
>   definição do manifesto do assembly localizado não corresponde à
>   referência do assembly. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80131040))

Já adicionei lá no Assembly o seguinte codigo:

```
<add assembly ="NPOI, Version=2.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0df73ec7942b34e1"/>
```

Alguem pode me dar uma luz?
Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Já consegui resolver, obrigado a quem se dispos a tentar resolver meu problema.

Até a próxima. (tomara que não tenha kkkk)